# jquery datepicker - wrap week number in tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker and I'm trying to add a little bit of my own styling to it - however - because the week number is just inserted straight into the table cell I am very limited with what I can do with it using just CSS.

Is there any way I can make the current format:

`<td class="ui-datepicker-week-col">40</td>`

look more like this

`<td class="ui-datepicker-week-col"><p>40</p></td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selector")
      .datepicker({ showWeek: true ,
                    onChangeMonthYear:function(a,b,c)
                                      {setTimeout(function(){$(c.input).trigger('update');},20);}
                  }).on('update',function(){$('.ui-datepicker-week-col',this).wrapInner('<p/>');})
                      .trigger('update');
  });
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7MqLn/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/7MqLn/)

But I would agree with Scott Selby, the selector `.ui-datepicker-week-col` is sufficient for a custom styling.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for except it doesn't work when the datepicker is attached to a text input because the datepicker is not rendered on pageload.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably run a JavaScript function after the table is generated.

I haven't tested this code, but this should be the approach.

```
var targetTag = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-datepicker-week-col");
```

Now this will give you all the elements as an array, like targetTag[0], targetTag[1], ...
Then you could run a for each loop and do this:

```
targetTag[i].innerHTML = "<p>" + targetTag[i].innerHTML + "</p>";
```

Note: Some older browsers may not support the getElementsByClassName JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

you have control of your jquery-ui css file , you can override anything in there to style the way you want,  I do not know of any way to change the HTML that gets rendered, like adding `<p>` to the date, but you can always do something like this in css

```
.ui-datepicker-week-col{
      display: inline !important;  // or however you want to change it
  }
```

or adding in HTML

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ui-datepicker-week-col{
        ...  /*HTML styling will override css file*/
         }
</style>
```

Comment: i agree this would be the best solution, but if you try to add padding and borders, it starts to look really messy. hence i'm wanting to add a tag to give me more options.